# MySQL 5.6 DATETIME doesn't accept milliseconds/microseconds

Tags: mysql

Running MySQL 5.6.7-rc which allegedly supports [fractional seconds in time values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html). Right...

Try this in MySQL Workbench 5.2.44:

```
CREATE TABLE T (dt DATETIME);
INSERT INTO T (dt) VALUES ('2012-11-12 13:54:00.123');
SELECT dt FROM T;
```

The output is this:

```
2012-11-12 13:54:00
```

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Found the answer. Data type should be `DATETIME(6)` for microseconds and `DATETIME(3)` for milliseconds.

`TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` column types also support fractional seconds with the same syntax.

For more information, consult the [MySQL Reference on Fractional Seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Comment: see MYSQL Manual [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html]

Comment: Broken link, must be https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html
Remove "]" at the end

Answer (score 3):

to get microseconds in mysql, call

```
SELECT MICROSECOND(dt) FROM T;
```

Comment: Useful for `DATETIME(6)`, but not the old `DATETIME` :/