# How to get current timestamp with milliseconds in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm able to get approximate time without milliseconds by query

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

but how to get precise current timestamp with milliseconds? 
For example, after executing the above query I get `1352717640` value, but I want to get `1352717640xxx` value.

**UPD**

And other answers from SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098185/mysql-unix-timestampnow-current-time-in-miliseconds)) offers solution like

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000;
```

but this query only fills up milliseconds place with '000', but I want to get PRECISE value of milliseconds, like `1352717640937`.

In SQLyog:

[image]

And in mysql console:

[image]

Is it possible at all for **MySQL 5.1**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 5.6 DATETIME doesn't accept milliseconds/microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344994/mysql-5-6-datetime-doesnt-accept-milliseconds-microseconds)

Comment: @McNets, but my question is completely different...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48098959/3270427

Comment: @McNets, but in this answer milliseconds only replaced with '000', but I want to get precise value of milliseconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql UNIX\_TIMESTAMP(now()) - current time in miliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098185/mysql-unix-timestampnow-current-time-in-miliseconds)

Answer (score 6):

I think you didn't test it, but yes the solution is

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/17727)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/17727/0)**:

```
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000 |
|-----------------------------|
|               1519827493419 |
```

Comment: Maybe the reason is MySQL version, because I tested it, and I always got '000' at the end. My version is 5.1...

Comment: Are you sure you are doing NOW(3) ?

Comment: It was executed in SQLyog.

Comment: And I had a thought, that it could be the bug of SQLyog, but in console I have the same output: http://joxi.ru/82QDYBqIjnDGqm

Comment: Can you try NOW() and NOW(3), I think it's a bug in your Mysql version

Comment: Both of these functions return the same result ('2018-03-01 15:13:28').

Comment: I am out of ideas, maybe you can ask a question how to do NOW(3) in mysql 5.1

Answer (score 2):

**Mysql 8.0.26**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000;
-- return float 1672434492831.000
```

**To integer:**

```
SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3))*1000);
-- return INT 1672434492831
```